# ¿Diferencias entre Seed, migrations y factories?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy aprendiendo Laravel, pero me causa conflicto entender algunas cosas con respecto al tema.

Según entendí las migraciones son una especia de control de versiones de la base de datos con POO

Los Seed sirven para crear datos de prueba.

Y los factories son supersets para los datos de pruebas.

Sin embargo, no entiendo muy claro los conceptos, y no sé muy bien como aplicarlos en Laravel, o un ejercicio.

Answer (score 4):

Comencemos la explicación

### 1. MIGRACIONES

Las migraciones, son la capaintermedia entre tu app y el gestor de bases de datos; me explico, cuando tradicionalmente desarrollas un software empiezas a crear tu modelo relacional en herramientas como por ejemplo Work Bench de MySQL o bien desde la consola creas cada una de las tablas que van a componer a tu base de datos, sin embargo Laravel como framework nos provee la capacidad de escribir cada tabla de nuestra base de datos en forma de migración; para que de esta manera se pueda generar un versionamiento de la misma.

La estructura de una migración es muy similar a esta que te muestro sin embargo depende de lo que estes intentando resolver

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('airline');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

> Cada migración representa una entidad/tabla de tu base de datos por lo
>   tanto el nombre que les coloques debe ser representativo de cada una
>   de ellas y no colocar mas de una a la vez

---

### 2. SEEDS

Los seeds son un método de Laravel que te va a permitir poblar de información de prueba tu base de datos; por lo tanto como notas para poder utilizar esta característica de Laravel ya antes debes tener creada tu base de datos (Aclaración para que esta cualidad funcione no depende de que tengas hechas migraciones), es decir tu perfectamente puedes crear tu base de datos de toda la vida y posterior usar esta herramienta de seed para igualmente llenar tus tablas de datos

Para poder empezar con los seeders, debes crearlos desde la consola como en el siguiente ejemplo

```
php artisan make:seeder UsersTableSeeder
```

Donde como puedes notar se nombra al seeder con el nombre que va a tener la tabla pero en singular.

¿Qué utlidad tienen entonces los seeders?

> Poblar de data de muestra tu base de datos con fines de testeo, queda
>   claro que no debe ser la base de datos de producción si no una de
>   prueba; te va a simplificar dicho proceso por que en vez de estar
>   llenando de forma manual cada tabla puedes tranquilamente generar
>   múltiples y hacer tests

Así mismo te comento los Seeders trabajan con el query Builder Fluent por lo tanto puedes observar en el ejemplo que en vez de inclocar al modelo, trabajan directamente invocando el nombre de la tabla

Ejemplo

```
public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => str_random(10),
            'email' => str_random(10).'@gmail.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('secret'),
        ]);
    }
```

---

### 3. MODEL FACTORIES

Son una herramienta para poblar de forma masiva también nuestra base de datos e incluso nos ayudan a escribir tests para la información ingresada, así mismo los Model Factories requieren de invocar al modelo que esta vinculado con alguna de tus tablas de tu base de datos

Ejemplo

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function ($faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'password' => str_random(10),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, añadiría que los seeder no sólo sirven para poblar con datos de testeo,  también son útiles para establecer datos Default en la base de datos al hacer deploy. Por ejemplo establecer usuario admin, los roles, o cosas similares.